# Aligning inline-blocks to the left

Tags: html, css, alignment

See this fiddle: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leoalfredmusic/TGV7z/)

I have two `div`s that I am displaying as inline blocks. For some reason my `div`s are coming up as centered, even though I want them aligned to the left. How can I align my divs so that the match up with my `.main` div and are left aligned?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this do it? http://jsfiddle.net/KU9CC/

Comment: No. Did you even change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of centering all `<body>` contents, center just what you want to center:

```
body {
    text-align: left; /* Just remove text-align:center */
}
h1, .click-nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TGV7z/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Elements set with inline-block act much like text. You need to have a parent container that has `text-align: left`. Right now, it's centered because the parent element is body which has `text-align: center`

Comment: I set `.click-nav` to `text-align: left` and all it did was align the text in the div, not the actual div to the left.

Comment: That's not quite what I was suggesting. It's about the parent of `.click-nav`
I'm assuming this is what you are trying to do?
http://jsfiddle.net/BeLTG/

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry! I understand now! Thank you! I would vote you up, but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Oh, that's not a problem. Glad your issue is solved :)